# Finding missing tables to avoid cross joins

Tags: sql, database, join

the user in my application can choose freely some fields from the database.

```
people
+ peopleid
+ peoplename

cars
+ carid
+ carnumber
+ carcolor

pers_car
+ carid
+ peopleid
```

Lets assume the user is selecting the fields peoplename and carcolor to find out which person likes which colours.

Is it possible to identify the missing pers_car-Table (needed for joining) if...

- the table and the fields doesn't have a nice name?
- differenciate between logical and unlogical requests from user?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How does your application work? What does it do if the user selects fields? Does it perform a search? And what is the problem with identifying the "missing table"? It's just the table that is not specified...

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clearer; otherwise it will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The first word in line (before "+") is the table name. The software removed my line breaks :(